Adding multiple durations together in google sheets breaking
I'm trying to figure out what I've done wrong to add multiple drive times together to find the total drive time.
In my sample sheet, I've got 2 travel schedules and using scripts, it's calculating the drive time to each new city in column D and then converting the text (5 hours, 32 mins) to format as duration (5:32).
In the 2nd set, the green schedule, it's both struggling with the 1 day 4 hour drive time but even when I just manually type in 28:00, the calculation in row 13 is not calculating all the durations.
I've been looking over this the past several days and can not figure out what I've done wrong.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13ODUpiUE95qkYh6JsbAqNzUwrdNICEXZ7-59INzF8lM/edit?usp=sharing

Use regexextract() and basic arithmetic, like this:
=sum(E3:E12)

=ifna(regexextract(D3, "(\d+) day")) + 
 ifna(regexextract(D3, "(\d+) hou") / 24) + 
 ifna(regexextract(D3, "(\d+) min") / 24 / 60)

See Solution and Working with date and time values in Google Sheets.

thank you SO much, I figured I was overthinking it!
